# get jackson to ignore a field in a map

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am combining Spring Boot and jongo/mongo to create a dynamic mongo app that does not use POJO's.  Everything in and out of the database is a `Map<String, Object>`.  I have everything working exactly the way I want, except one thing.  I don't want to send `_id` from mongo to the client.  This system uses a "mark obsolete and insert new record" style of updates so we can maintain a change history for the document.  therefore, I don't want any client to even be tempted to use the `_id` field, I have another I want them to use.

Now I find all kinds of examples on how to ignore fields in pojo's, but i want to write a Jackson Map serializer that ignores a specific value of the map.  I can't find anything like that yet.  I suppose gson would do as well, I just don't currently have spring configured for gson.

any idea how to write this serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not try to make Jackson make the work mongo can simply do.

The [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) explicitly has a use case that is named *Return All But the Excluded Fields* which is exactly what you want:

```
db.inventory.find( { fieldA: "A" }, { _id: 0 } )
```

*Get all documents with fieldA set to "A", return all fields, except for the `_id` field.*

You course the query above is the JavaScript Mongo query language, but you should not get problems to convert it to the Mongo Java api.

Comment: Perfect.  In Jongo the line ended up being `inventory.find().projection("{ _id: 0 }").as(Map.class)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) in your project, filter your map:

```
Map<String, Object> filtered = Maps.filterKeys(map, (k)-> !"_id".equals(k));
```

Serialize the filtered map.

Without Guava, make a copy of the map. Call `copy.remove("_id")`.
Serialize copy.